# Does every open orientable even-dimensional smooth manifold admit an almost complex structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Does every open orientable even-dimensional smooth manifold admit an almost complex structure?

Comment: Even dimensional?

Comment: Gromov proved that on any open manifold of real dimension less than or equal to 6, almost complex structures exist if and only if complex structures exist.

Comment: @BenMcKay yes, even-dimensional.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Gromov, M. (1973) Convex integration of differential relations, Izv. Akad. Nauk S.S.S.R. 37, # 2, pp. 329-343.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: also Gromov, Partial Differential Relations, p. 103.

Comment: Another interesting related result of Gromov (in his PhD thesis) about open manifolds is that they admit a almost complex structure $\iff$ they admit a symplectic form (very different to the compact case where there is an existance conjecture but it remains open in dimensions $\geq 6$).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If $M$ admits an almost complex structure, then the odd Stiefel-Whitney classes vanish and the even Stiefel-Whitney classes admit integral lifts, namely $c_i(M) \equiv w_{2i}(M) \bmod 2$. These two conditions give restrictions on the smooth manifolds which can admit almost complex structures.

The first restriction, namely that $w_1(M) = 0$, is equivalent to orientability. If $M$ is orientable, then the second restriction, namely that $w_2(M)$ admits an integral lift, is equivalent to the manifold being spin$^c$.

An example of an orientable non-spin$^c$ manifold is the Wu manifold $SU(3)/SO(3)$ which has dimension five. Therefore $M = (SU(3)/SO(3))\times\mathbb{R}^{2k+1}$ is an open orientable even-dimensional manifold which does not admit an almost complex structure.

Note that $\dim M = 2k + 6$, so this gives examples in all positive even dimensions other than two and four. It turns out that in dimensions two and four, there are no examples.

- In dimension two, a manifold is almost complex if and only if it is orientable.
- In dimension four, an open manifold admits an almost complex structure if and only if it is spin$^c$, and every orientable four-manifold is spin$^c$, see [this note](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eteichner/Papers/spin.pdf) by Teichner and Vogt.

Comment: Great answer! I had thought that was the case. I was just reading your paper https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1905.01760/ in there it says the connected sum of two closed 4d AC manifolds is never AC (almost complex). This seems contrary to your above statement. I'm sure I'm missing something? NOTE: technically the paper says in dimension 4m m in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @R.Rankin: Note that the four-dimensional statement in my answer above only applies to open manifolds, not closed manifolds.

Comment: Thank you, your work comes up a lot in my "adventures"